# Build IOS codemagic fail

Tags: flutter, codemagic

I'm trying to deploy my app to the Apple Store using Codemagic since I don't have a Macbook

I'm having a problem as you can see in the screenshot

thank you for helping me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. you can check logs from `Set up code signing identities` step to make sure that you has correct profile installed
2. also you need to check bundle id in Xcode project settings. If you don't have Mac computer you can use [remote access](https://docs.codemagic.io/troubleshooting/accessing-builder-machine-via-ssh) to Codemagic builder machine. Also I recommend to read next article https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-build-and-distribute-ios-apps-without-mac-with-flutter-codemagic/ as it covers major problems developing building iOS apps without Mac